# Как правильно конвертировать белый png в svg

Tags: svg, png

Здравствуйте. Хочу использовать на сайте картинки svg вместо png.

Проблема 1. Есть png файлы, но большая часть из них белые на прозрачном фоне. Черные переводятся без проблем, а вот белые - в результате просто белый квадрат.. использовал онлайн конверторы типа http://www.online-convert.com, illustrator, но результат тот же... пробовал в illustrator инструмент силуэты (возможно не правильно пользуюсь)...

Проблема 2. Хочу сделать с этих картинок svg спрайт. Как его лучше подключить написано много, есть споры... но всё-таки как это сделать  по best practics? (возможно личный опыт)

Answer (score 1):

Растрирование белой картинки с помощью [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ваш вариант ответа. я заменял цвет в фотошопе на чёрный и тогда уже нормально распознавалось, по времени одинаково...